# Запаковать видео в бинарный файл

Tags: php, facebook-api, facebook-graph-api

Пытаюсь загрузить видео на Facebook через Graph-Api, там указано:

> video_file_chunk((multipart/form-data) - тип - Бинарный файл

Есть у меня видео, я его зачитываю так

```
$file = fopen($video, 'r');
$read = fread($file, $video_size);
```

При выводе получаются кракозябры всякие

> ftypmp42isommp42�moovlmvhd�9l/�9l/X#_@iodsO��)��trak\tkhd|%���9l/#@@hBmdia mdhd|%���9l/xU�-hdlrvideVideoHandler�minfvmhd$dinfdrefurl �stbl�stsd�avc1hHH��/avcCB���gB�

Если я просто отправляю через CURL

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "video_file_chunk=$read");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
        'Content-Type:multipart/form-data'
    ]);
```

То фб выдаёт ошибку

> Загрузка вашего видео была прервана до завершения. Может быть медленное подключение к сети или видео, которое вы пытаетесь загрузить, слишком велико. Пожалуйста, попробуйте еще раз.

Я отловил запрос Facebook, и когда он грузит файлы себе он файл этот кодирует вот в такую строку

> 1:dW6kZZZpbmGs:application/octet-stream:GKZL1wEsTeKApcQBAHMCylVe4PsFbugbAAAP:e:1566747613:ARbvLu_E69y8_Lk6ZNE

Поэтому я думаю что дело в том, как я передаю этот видео файл...

**Как эти кракозябры, правильно запаковать в бинарный файл, чтобы отправить на Facebook?**

Comment: А какой размер видео facebook разрешает загрузить, какой у вас размер видео. Нашел еще SDK от facebook по загрузки видео, может его попробовать https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_upload_video

Comment: @ЕвгенийГаврилов пытаюсь отправить и маленькое видео( до 1 мб), и большое, (70мб) - и все-равно фб выдаёт такой ответ при любом размере. Видимо дело все-таки в том как видео пакуется. То что SDK есть знаю, но мне SDK не подходит к сожалению